# How to catch event that was stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, dom-events, stoppropagation

For example we have a page with a link that has `onclick` event listener on it. But handler makes `stopPropagation`. How I can handle that `click` event was made, if it's not bubble to root anymore?

e.g.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {console.log(e);});
a.onclick = function(e) {e.stopPropagation();};
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? In this case you have to catch the click before the propagation is stopped. If you want to stopPropagation AND notify the document you could trigger a custom event.

Comment: DOM event propagation works in three phases: the capture phase, the target phase and the bubble phase. Roughly, the event first works its way down to the target, reaches the target and then works its way back up. If you attach a click event listener in the capture phase, the other event handlers `stopPropagation` should have no effect. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) for a deeper explanation.

Comment: Thanks @janfoeh! It's exactly what I was looking for. Please add that as an answer, I'll accept it. `document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {console.log(e);}, true);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DOM event propagation works in three phases: the capture phase, the target phase and the bubble phase. Roughly, the event first works its way down to the target, reaches the target and then works its way back up.

By default, event handlers are attached in the final bubble phase. If you attach a click event listener in the first capture phase, it will run before the previous handler has had the chance to call `stopPropagation`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) for a deeper explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is, **add a third argument, `true`, when adding your event listener**.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', someFunction, true)
```

[This flag (called `useCapture`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters) will call `someFunction` on all clicks in a document, even when the user clicked inside an element with a click handler that called `event.stopPropagation`.

### With options

If you're already passing an object of options as the third argument, simply include `capture: true` in them:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', someFunction, { capture: true, ...someMoreOptions })
```

---

### Why?

Enabling the handler's `useCapture` mode like this means the listener listens during the earlier "capture" phase of the event (which starts at the outmost element then trickles down through children), instead of the later "bubble" phase (which starts at the innermost element and bubbles back up through ancestors, and is the one `stopPropagation` blocks).

### Side effects

That also means that applying this setting changes the timing: your capture phase click event will occur before any click events of either type inside child or descendant elements.

For example, in the above function, if a user clicks on a button on the page, the `someFunction` attached to the `document`'s capture phase will be called before any handlers attached to the button; whereas without setting use capture to true, you'd expect it to be called after.